# CSS / HTML : Designing with pixels for multi DPI devices? Retaining same size?

Tags: css, html, mobile, sass

I started to design a div which is supposed to represent a mobile header. I designed it using a height in pixels, problem is that this looks different on other mobiles. I think this is the issue of pixels are not DPIs.

In the android world this is easily fixed. I am using a standard HTML website, I am using a bootstrap grid with scss (sass).

Is there some way to allow the height to remain the exact height on each device that has a different DPI ratio?

Really lost here, I presume this problem has a solution?

I think this problem is also going to be the same for pixels and images, on some devices its going to occupy a different amount of space between different device DPI's. What is the solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use em instead of pixels, em are relative to the device standard font size

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? So if i have an image that is 100 pixels by 100 pixels what em should I be using ? Is there some standard size calculator ?

Comment: divide desired font-size in pixels by standard font-size, so in case of google chrome browser the standard is 16px which gives us 100 / 16 = 6.25em. Safari browsers on iphone have 12px standard, so if you use 6.25 em the image will auto scale to 75px.